# Combining multiple commands to single output

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

This code works when ran on its own, I'm trying to combine both commands output to a single csv, formatted with the correct headers.

```
$objectIDs = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId x | select objectid,displayname,mail

$groups = foreach ($objectID in $objectids) {
    Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $objectid.ObjectId | select mail ;
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $objectID.ObjectId | Where-Object { $_.displayname -like '*xxxxxxxx*' } | select displayname
 
}

$groups | Out-File C:\temp\test.csv
```

Basically, I need the mail and specific group name in a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the wanted values like below:

```
$objectIDs = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId x | Select-Object objectid,displayname,mail

$groups = foreach ($objectID in $objectids) {
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $objectid.ObjectId
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $objectID.ObjectId | Where-Object { $_.displayname -like '*xxxxxxxx*' } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'email'; Expression = {$user.mail}}, displayname
}

$groups | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Please note that if the output should be a structured CSV file, you need to use `Export-Csv` on the resulting objects instead of `Out-File`